# SQL Server Select a row for where a column value does not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as

```
COl1____COL2____COL3
1_________1_____val1
1_________2_____val2
1_________3_____val3

2_________1_____val1
2_________2_____val2
2_________3_____val3

3_________1_____val1
3_________2_____val2
3_________4_____val4
```

No I want to have unique values from COL1 such that it should only show me COL1 value that does not have a value "3" under COL2

i.e. I want a query to return me

```
Result
3
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT col1
FROM   YourTable
EXCEPT
SELECT col1
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  col2 = 3
```

Or

```
SELECT col1
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY col1
HAVING MAX(CASE
             WHEN Col2 = 3 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.. the 1st answer is absolutely what I was looking for.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

```
select col1
from Tab
where col1 not in (select col1 from tab where col2 = 3)
```

Comment: This answer seems appropriate but i guess this is not the most effective one.. still I'll go with this for now..

Comment: No buddy.. u r not missing anything.. just that my table is huge with hundreds of thousand of records, so that is why.. other wise your solution is perfectly all rite..